# DateTimeControl blank in asp form

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint DateTimeControl in an asp form, the dropdown boxes are not displaying any values however.

```
 <td class="ms-formbody">
    <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dateTimeCurfewIn" runat="server" TimeOnly="true" HoursMode24="true"/>
 </td>
```

Is there something special I need to add to this to get the time to display in the dropdown boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works. Maybe try to add

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

if you didn't it before. Here [DateTimeControl Control](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/datetimecontrol-control/) is full the control properties description.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common method for this, hope it will help someone with the same issue.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get common SP DateTimeControl with current DateOnly settings and MethodToProcessDateChanged
/// </summary>
public static DateTimeControl Cd(this bool DateOnly, bool AutoPostBack = false,
DateTime? SelectedDate = null, Func<bool> MethodToProcessDateChanged = null)
{
     var d = new DateTimeControl();
     d.DateOnly = DateOnly;
     d.AutoPostBack = AutoPostBack;
     if (SelectedDate != null)
     d.SelectedDate = SelectedDate.Value;
     if (MethodToProcessDateChanged != null)
          d.DateChanged += (o, e) => { MethodToProcessDateChanged();};
     return d;
}
```

See more details [here](https://pizza-soft.ru/2018/11/18/spdatetimecontrol/)